# What does the ? mean when outputting a string using printf and is strcmp supposed to return a zero for matches (in C)?

Tags: c, strcmp

Point of HW is it should read this from a file:

```
int func(int arg) { int x = 7; char c = 'a'; arg = x + c; return arg; }
```

and output this:

```
func, arg, x, c
//or optionally also the next line
int, char, return
```

So my issue is on getting question marks on my output for characters that should be appearing, and strcmp is not returning a zero for my if statement which requires it to work (note: I have a lot of comments and printf's to help me figure out where I am going wrong):

```
while((d=fgetc(function_file)) != EOF) {
    //start by checking for any defines and just looping until a new line character comes up
    if( d == '#')
        flag = true;

    if((d == '\n') && (flag)){
        //flag which says if I am searching for a newline but only after a define/include 
        //was found will I say the flag is not needed anymore to allow normal parsing
        flag = false;
    } //end of check for a define function

    if( (flag == false) && (d != '#') ) {

        //this is where the main chunk of code goes to do all the parsing
        if((d != ' ') && (d != '\t') && (d !='\n') && (d != '{') && (d != '}') && (d != '(') && (d != ')') && (d != '*') && (d != '=') && (d != '+')) {

            printf("Character read is : %c\n", d);
            start = true;
            temp[count] = c;
            count++;
        }


    }//end of main chunk of code
        if((start == true) && ((d == ' ') || (d == '(') || (d == ')') || (d == '{') || (d == '}'))) {
            //end a string and compare it hear
            if(match == false) {
            temp[count] = '\0';
        printf("String: %s\n", temp);//*********************************DEBUGGING***********

            start = false;
            int compare;
            for(compare = 0; compare < key_counter; compare++) {
                int optimus;
                optimus = strcmp(keywords[compare], temp); //************** ONE OF THE ERRORS IS HERE***************************************?
                if(optimus == 0){
                    //printf("this is actually runnning");//*********************************DEBUGGING***********
                    int len = strlen(temp);
                    bizarro_keywords[bizarro_key_counter] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len +1));
                    memcpy(bizarro_keywords[bizarro_key_counter], temp, len +1);
                    printf("\nWhats inside bizarro_key_counter right after it is allocated memory: %s", bizarro_keywords[bizarro_key_counter]);
                    bizarro_key_counter++;
                    match = true;
                }

            }

            int x;
            for(x = 0; x < count; x++)
                temp[x] = '\0';
            count = 0;


        } else { //if match equals true just grab the next available string 
            //printf("is this one ever running?");
            temp[count] = '\0';
            start = false;
            printf("String: %s\n", temp);

                    int len = strlen(temp);
                    identifiers[iden_counter] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len +1));
                    memcpy(identifiers[iden_counter], temp, len +1);
                    iden_counter++;
                    match = false;



                    int x;
                    for(x = 0; x < count; x++)
                        temp[x] = '\0';
                    count = 0;

            }   
        }

}//end of while loop for reading the whole file
```

This is my output:

```
Character read is : i
Character read is : n
Character read is : t
String: ???
Character read is : f
Character read is : u
Character read is : n
Character read is : c
String: ????
Character read is : i
Character read is : n
Character read is : t
String: ???
Character read is : a
Character read is : r
Character read is : g
String: ???
Character read is : i
Character read is : n
Character read is : t
String: ???
Character read is : x
String: ?
Character read is : 7
Character read is : ;
String: ??
Character read is : c
Character read is : h
Character read is : a
Character read is : r
String: ????
Character read is : c
String: ?
Character read is : '
Character read is : a
Character read is : '
Character read is : ;
String: ????
Character read is : a
Character read is : r
Character read is : g
String: ???
Character read is : x
String: ?
Character read is : c
Character read is : ;
String: ??
Character read is : r
Character read is : e
Character read is : t
Character read is : u
Character read is : r
Character read is : n
String: ??????
Character read is : a
Character read is : r
Character read is : g
Character read is : ;
String: ????
```

I am new to C, and I am lost as to why I am getting that output. Hints please.

Comment: Try to remove redundant code so that we are able to understand your problem. Identify the problem you are dealing with and try to create a simple example of this situation.

Comment: You're probably not printing what you think you're printing.

Comment: Well I will remove the extra comments but the simplest solution is at the top with what I am suppose to be doing, or what the end result should be. Sorry for the amount of info tho.

Comment: @Andy: What LihO means is that you've just given us *all* your code, which we now have to wade through.  You should cut this down to a simple 10 line application that focuses on the *specific* problem that you're encountering.  Take a look at http://sscce.org.

Comment: @CarlNorum Well I thought that too, but I tested that out and it does contain what I need. Problem is mainly with why its printing the questions marks. If you look, you"ll notice that they match the previous characters, but they aren't appearing. Maybe I am using the wrong escape characters in printf?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Oh, ok, I see, I will do that. I thought it was necessary due to where some variables come from, but I will change that now

Comment: you should certainly have a look on [fscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp), [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy), and also http://thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you just want to read line from the input file and split it into tokens. You could use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) function instead of reading characters from the file:

```
char* keywords[] = { "int", "char", "return" };
int i = 0, j, keywordsCount = 3;
FILE* f = fopen("a.txt", "r");
char line[1000], *token;
while (fgets(line, 1000, f) != NULL) // read line
{
    char* token = strtok(line, " \t\n{}()*+=,;");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("String %d:%s", i++, token);

        for (j = 0; j < keywordsCount; ++j)
            if (strcmp(token, keywords[j]) == 0)
            {
                printf(" <-- Look, it's keyword!");
                break; // breaks for, not while
            }

        putchar('\n');
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n{}()*+=,;");
    }
}
```

Note that I use `'\n'` character in delimiters string because `fgets` function reads line into buffer that will include `'\n'` at the end.

Content of file `a.txt`:

```
int func(int arg) { int x = 7; char c = 'a'; arg = x + c; return arg; }
```

Output:

```
String 0:int <-- Look, it's keyword!
String 1:func
String 2:int <-- Look, it's keyword!
String 3:arg
String 4:int <-- Look, it's keyword!
String 5:x
String 6:7
String 7:char <-- Look, it's keyword!
String 8:c
String 9:'a'
String 10:arg
String 11:x
String 12:c
String 13:return <-- Look, it's keyword!
String 14:arg
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but is strtok not a regular expression? We aren't suppose to use those if it is. If its not, then I could definitely use it.

Comment: @Andy: No, `strtok` is not a regular expression. It's standard function that splits string into tokens by using string of delimiters (`" \t{}()*+=,;"`).

Comment: @Andy: If strtok suits you, you could edit your question so it is perfectly clear what you are trying to do. I'm now sure how exactly should output of your program look, but it will be definitely much easier if you use functions like `strtok`...

Comment: Yes, I will probably use the function because I did not know about it. I really appreciate it. One thing that I haven't got answered, though I know there is a lot of code. My strcmp() function is not returning a zero. I tested my keywords char pointer array, and it definitely has everything in it. So when it compares, it never finds a zero. Any ideas?

Comment: @Andy: In code you provided in your question doesn't show declaration of `keywords` variable. `strcmp` works fine, you are just using it wrong. Check my answer now.

Comment: When I was debugging it, strcmp never returned zero. But I will just change how I am doing it. I was researching strtok(), and in your code I don't understand why the second time you called it it had different delimiters? Actually it looks like its just 1 delimiter off. Is that just a typo? When I looked on the man pages it said every subsequent call to strtok, I need to pass in a NULL pointer. Is that why?

Comment: @Andy: That was typo. Good catch. `\n` should not be there since `gets` will never read it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8039/discussion-between-andy-and-liho)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit difficult to read - at least part four (despite the comments) because it is just too long.

You should split up your function into several smaller ones, you even already have the structure in place step 1-4. Now since you are reusing variables declared before there may sneak in issues like `count` not being == 0 when you get to step four. since there are so many twist and turns its a bit difficult to see the problem

when you such lexical analysis it is often better to use a state machine, switch statements are good for this e.g.

```
typedef enum { Idle, Include , ... } states_t;
states_t state=Idle;

switch (state)
{
   case Idle:
      switch ( d )
      { 
         case '#':
           state = Include;
           break;
     ...
     break;
   case Include:
     ...
     break;

      break;
```

if you don't have a debugger include assert.h and put asserts in your code to make sure all assumptions are caught i.e. `assert( count == 0 );` before step four may be a good thing.

use `strcpy` or better `strncpy` instead of memcpy when copying, the `strcpy`-family stops to copying when it encounters a \0 which is a bit more effective (it copies the \0 as well).